# Delegate actionsource to inner composite component

Tags: jsf, nested, composite-component

Please help to find out the problem.
I have two composite components:
ajaxCommandButton:

```
<cc:interface>
        <cc:actionSource name="ajaxAction" targets="ajaxCmd" />
        <cc:attribute name="action" targets="ajaxCmd" method-signature="void action()" />
        <cc:attribute name="value" />
        <cc:attribute name="title" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
            <h:commandButton value="#{cc.attrs.value}" id="ajaxCmd"
                             title="#{cc.attrs.title}" >
                <f:ajax />
            </h:commandButton>
    </cc:implementation>
```

and treeItem:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:actionSource name="itemAction" targets="ajaxAction" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <ccb:ajaxCommandButton value="test" action="#{action()}" id="ajaxAction">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener for="ajaxAction" value="#{value}" target="#{beanProperty}" />
    </ccb:ajaxCommandButton>
</cc:implementation>
```

and usage from ui:composition

```
<ccb:treeItem>
        <f:setPropertyActionListener for="ajaxAction" value="#{value}" target="#{beanProperty}" />
</ccb:treeItem>
```

What right way to set actionSource from ui:composition to ccb:ajaxCommandButton ?

Thanks in advance!